# jQuery nouislider Vertical Orientation Not Working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Can you pleae take a [look at this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/TM6nk/) and let me know why this vertical slider not even showing up? The orginal presentation is on [This Page](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/#sample-showcase) but it is not working for me!

```
$("#sample-showcase").noUiSlider({
     range: [0, 100]
    ,start: [20, 80]
    ,handles: 2
    ,step: 10
    ,margin: 20
    ,connect: true
    ,direction: 'rtl'
    ,orientation: 'vertical'
    ,behaviour: 'tap-drag'
    ,serialization: {
         mark: ','
        ,resolution: 0.1
        ,to: [ $("#value-input"),
              [$('#value-span'), 'html'] ]
    }
});
```

or do you probably know any vertical slider to introduce me? I Google it but didn't find any thing
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The slider is initialized properly; your js isn't at fault.

Due to the nature of the CSS box model, elements don't assume a default height. noUiSlider can't pick an arbitrary value, so it sets none. Therefore, to get the slider to show up properly:

**CSS:**

```
#sample-showcase { height: 300px; }
```

Comment: I'm appreciative of a developer supporting his own open source scripts in the Stack. Thanks.